# Monomorphism between abelianizated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I want to find an example of a group monomorphism,
$$\begin{matrix}\phi:&G_1&\longrightarrow&G_2
\end{matrix}$$
such that,
$$\begin{matrix}\bar\phi:&Ab(G_1)&\longrightarrow&Ab(G_2)
\end{matrix}$$
isn't monomorphism, where $Ab(G)$ is the abelianization of $G$. I have been told that a good way to find an example is using that there is a subgroup $H\subset L_2$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $L_3$. But I don't really know how to start from here.

Comment: The smallest nonabelian group has order $6$, so why not try that for $G_2$? It has subgroups of order $1,2,3$ and $6$, and orders $1$ and $6$ are not promising, so you could try $G_1$ or order $2$ or $3$.

Comment: I want to say the expected adjective would be *abelianized*, but now I think I'm voting for *abelianated*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $L_n$ is the free group ("libre") on $n$ generators. Let $L_2 = \langle x, y \rangle$ be freely generated by $x$ and $y$. Let $H < L_2$ be the subgroup generated by $x^2$, $xy$ and $yx$. The $H$ is free on these three generators (a combinatorics trick, it's explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem#Example)), i.e. $H \cong L_3$.

Of course the inclusion $H \hookrightarrow L_2$ is a monomorphism. However, the abelianisations of $H$ and $L_2$ are respectively $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so the induced map $\mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ cannot be a monomorphism (indeed, the three generators are sent to $(2,0) = [x^2] \in L_2/[L_2, L_2] \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, $(1,1) = [xy]$ and $(1,1) = [yx]$).

Answer (score 3):

Consider any monomorphism from some finite abelian group of odd order greater than 121 to the finite symmetric group (hence the symmetric group is $S_n$, for $n\ge 5$.) Note that the abelization of the symmetric group is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ or trivial, so the corresponding morphism must be trivial.

Comment: Why greater than $121$?

Comment: @DerekHolt It just forces the symmetric group containing the group greater than $S_5$.

Comment: That certainly works, but is there any other way using the tip? I'm trying to follow by myself a course on algebraic topology and I've been told by a friend that the other way would be more usefull to educate intuition for that matter.

Comment: @Smurf I hardly know about algebraic topology, so I can't explain it in the language of geometry or topology.

Comment: But since the abelianization of $S_n$ has order $2$, any abelian group of odd order greater than $1$ will work.